# Rewriting URLs within the webpage with a subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy

I've setup a reverse proxy and using mod_rewrite to rewrite the URLs. The issue I'm facing is that all the URLs in my webpage go to http://domainname.com/pagename

However, I want it to go to http://domainname.com/dir/pagename

I've tried a bunch of Rewrites but none seem to work.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:*>
ProxyPreserveHost On

# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example:
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<Directory /var/www/>

            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>

            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>



<VirtualHost *:*>
 # Proxy specific settings
 ProxyRequests Off

 <Proxy *>
 AddDefaultCharset off
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Proxy>
   ServerName do.domain.com

   ProxyPassReverse blog.domain.com do.domain.com/blog/
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^blog.(.*)$  do.cdomain.com/blog/$1 [P]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is this for Apache2? Please share your directory setup as well as your config file.

Comment: Yes. It's for Apache2. Sharing the config file.

Comment: File added. Could you please check?